# What should I know about combining a Ruby on Rails app with a .NET system?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails

I am a novice in Ruby on Rails and I have never used .NET, so thanks for any help you can provide!

I have a web app built in Ruby on Rails that uses a MySQL database. I'm talking to another company that may be interested in integrating my entire app into its system. The other company has a large, enterprise .NET system with a SQL server system.

My goal is to get a sense of the challenge involved in combining these two systems. Does my app really provide value to the other company, or will it have to start from scratch and recreate the entire thing in .NET?

I'm glad to provide more information; I'm just not sure what details are required to get a sense of the challenge involved in combining the two systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if all is web and you want to integrate, the keyword is [webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). You can do anything you want using [remote procedure calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) with formats like [XMLRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlrpc) or, the one I like best, [JSON RPCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).

Basically you will make POSTS, GETS (and possibly PUTS and DELETES) to the server to modify it state or to retrieve information from it. If the people from ASP wants to help, I advise you to define an interface along with them about the expected requests and answers, including error handling, and do the communication this way.

Your question is way to big and it is hard to answer, but I hope this give you a guideline.

Comment: Thanks @fotanus. Your reply helped clarify the breadth of this project a little for me.